# Dense Graph $G(T)\subset H\times H$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

The following construction appears to yield a dense Graph in $H\times H$
where $H$ is a seperable Hilbert-space.

Take $\{x_n\}$ a countable dense subset of $H$. Let $\{e_n\}$ an orthonormal basis of $H$, and define $Te_n :=x_n$. Then extend $T$ linearly to $D(T)$.

Then $G(T)$ is dense. Why?

How can we construct a sequence $(x_k, Tx_k)$  such that we reach every $(x,y) \in H\times H$. Or is there a more straightforward approach? Any ideas, or suggestions are welcome. (It is Rudin Excercise 13.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(x,y)\in H\times H$ and $\varepsilon>0$. Clearly, there exist $a_1,\ldots,a_n$, s.t.
$$
\|a_1e_1+\cdots+a_ne_n-x\|<\varepsilon.
$$
Let $z=y-(a_1x_1+\cdots+ a_nx_n)$. As $\{x_n\}$ is dense in $H$, there is an $m>n$, such that $\|x_m-z/\varepsilon\|<1$. Let $w=z-\varepsilon x_m$, then $\|w\|<\varepsilon$ and
$$
T(a_1e_1+\cdots+a_ne_n+\varepsilon e_m)=T(a_1e_1+\cdots+a_ne_n)+\varepsilon Te_m=y-z+\varepsilon x_m=y-w,
$$
and hence
$$
\|T(a_1e_1+\cdots+a_ne_n+\varepsilon e_m)-y\|=\|w\|<\varepsilon.
$$
Altogether
$$
\big\|\big(x,y\big)-\big(a_1e_1+\cdots+a_ne_n+\varepsilon e_m,
T(a_1e_1+\cdots+a_ne_n+\varepsilon e_m)\big)\big\| < 3\varepsilon.
$$
QED

Comment: that looks neat. But I dont quite grasp why you could take a different $\epsilon´$ and everything still works..why is this $\epsilon´$ such that $||a_1e_1+\cdots +a_ne_n+\epsilon´e_m - x|| < \epsilon$? Thatś what you use right? Iḿ little puzzled by this change of epsilon.

Comment: I guess we want to add up a little bit of (smaller) $\epsilon x_m$ to $a_1e_1 + \cdots + a_ne_n$ so that the difference in norm with $x$ is still sufficiently small. I guess that is possible, but I am not 100% sure why. Maybe its obvious.

Comment: Actually, you are right. No need for an additional $\varepsilon$ - Correction done.

Comment: Ok, thatś very neat. I see now. Thank you kindly for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, $T$ is definable only in a dense subset of $H$, as
$$
T\Big(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_ne_n\Big)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx_n,
$$
is definable only if the sum in the right hand side converges absolutely in the $H$-norm. But it is definable for finite sums, which are dense.

Comment: Sorry, I know that $D(T)$ is dense in $H$, which like you mentioned can only contain finite sums. The actual idea of showing that $G(T)$ is dense is not clear to me at all. The $H\times H$-norm is $||(x,y)||² = ||x||²+ ||y||² $. It is not obvious at all why we can find a converging sequence in $H\times H$-norm so that $(x_n, Tx_n)\to (x,y) \in H \times H$